# (C++) Passing a vector of objects to a constructor

Tags: c++, object, vector, constructor

```
class A {
public:
   int value;
   A(int value){
       this->value = value;
   }
};

class Relation{
    vector<A> items;

    Relation(vector<A> items){
       this->items = items;
    }
}

int main(){
   vector<A> items;
   items.push_back(A(1));

   Relation r1(items);
}
```

How do I pass a vector of my new object to a constructor of another object? In line 13, I get an error "no matching function for call to 'A::A()' "

Comment: Which line is 13?

Comment: I don't get that error. Instead I get the error that `Relation::Relation` constructor is private which is easily fixable.

Comment: putting Relation constructor public there is no error when compiling

Comment: There's a missing semicolon in the shown code. Even ignoring the missing include files, and missing namespace declaration, this is evidence that the shown code is not the real code in question, and attempting to guess what the problem is, here, will be a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    int value;
    A(const int value1 = 0) : value(value1) {}
};

class Relation {
    std::vector<A> items;
public:
    Relation(std::vector<A> items1) : items(items1) {};
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<A> items;
    items.push_back(A(1));

    Relation r1(items);
}
```

Several changes are made to conform to usual C++ practice. The most important is probably that `Relation`'s contructor is exposed for `public` use.

Comment: Thanks. But I also tried adding default constructor to class "A" which takes no arguments and that helped too.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Comment: I think that changing `items.push_back(A(1))` to `items.emplace_back(1)` is a less intrusive solution than adding a default constructor for the `A`-class.

Comment: @JoakimThorén Good point. Add that as an *answer* and ping me in the comments as "@thb" so that the system notifies me. I will upvote.

Comment: @thb On a second thought, you don't actually *need* a default constructor in your solution either. It compiles just fine without it. Of course, using `emplace_back` regardless has its benefits but it does not really have anything to do with the default constructor in this case (or the question posed by OP).

Comment: @JoakimThorén Quite right. Adding a default constructor won't hurt, though. OP wanted to try it. Sounds like good practice for him, so I didn't object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this happens because the elements in class Relation are private as of now, try adding `public:` before any declaration. And use the semicolon (`;`) after your class declaration as well as a return in your main function.

Comment: _" as well as a return in your main function"_ No, that's not necessary.

Comment: by default _main_ returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Relation's constructor must be public. Also, all the "this->" are not necessary. It ends to something like this:

```
class A {
public:
   int value;

   A(int value)
   {
       value = value;
   }
};

class Relation{
    vector<A> items;

public:
    Relation(const vector<A>& values)
    {
       items = values;
    }
};

int main(){
   vector<A> items;
   items.push_back(A(1));

   Relation r1(items);
}
```